# Powershell Group Names Returning With No Spaces

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I am using `get-WmiObject -class Win32_Group` to get a list of groups to interrogate. I am having the issue of no naming convention. There are group names like `Admin Users` , `AdminUsers`, `Admin_Users`, `Admin WWW Users`, `Admin Users_`, etc.

My issue is that when the group name is returned, the spaces are removed. So I'll end up with something like `AdminUsers`, `AdminUsers`, `Admin_Users`, AdminWWWUsers, `AdminUsers_`, etc.

As you can see some will work and some will end up broken. I handled some issues with Regex but ALL of the conditions are getting out of control (started simple, expanding as I started noticing there was no naming convention).

How can I return the list of group names as they exist, so I can look them up for interrogation.

I have had no luck finding a solution to this, but I'm sure it can be done!

Comment: I suspect that this all stems from your statement '*I handled some issues with Regex*', and that you removed spaces to try and match similar names or some such. Without seeing more of your script I don't think we can help much.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 8/Server 2012 and above, you can utilize the following cmdlet:

```
Get-LocalGroup | Select-Object -Property 'Name'
```

Although, I was unable to replicate your issue with spaces stripped from WMI information.

Comment: For what it is worth I cannot replicate missing spaces in names either. Corrupt WMI would be my first suspicion.

Comment: Really!? That's interesting, I'm going to re-examine my script now. Will post back.

Comment: For before win 8/2012 you could try wrapping  good old `net group` in an `invoke-command` for remoting and parse the output, albiet a hacky solution.